# How to get local hour of date time in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework, mlab

This is  document in a Data base.

```
 {
   "_id" : "E08AF4BD-5539-497E-B8DA-51AD1A14F7A7",
   "checkinCategory" : "Transient",
   "checkinData" : {
       "time" : ISODate("2018-01-19T09:52:03.708+05:30"),
       "dateFormat" : "2018-1-19",
      "addedOn" : ISODate("2018-01-19T09:52:08.514+05:30"),
      "checkinId" : "E08AF4BD-5539-497E-B8DA-51AD1A14F7A7"
    }
}
```

> I am using aggregate Query and trying to get hour from checkinData.time.

```
db.checkins.aggregate(
    {"$match":
         {"_id":"E08AF4BD-5539-497E-B8DA-51AD1A14F7A7"}},
         {"$project":{"checkinData.time":1, 
                       hour: { $hour: ("$checkinData.time")}

    }}
})
```

> Mongo returns

```
 {
   "_id" : "E08AF4BD-5539-497E-B8DA-51AD1A14F7A7",
    "checkinData" : {
         "time" : ISODate("2018-01-19T09:52:03.708+05:30")
     },
   "hour" : 4
 }
```

I want to get hour in **ISO format like 9**. Plz sugget me where am I doing wrong..Thanks!

Comment: Try `{ hour:{ $hour: {
    date: "$checkinData.time",
    timezone: "Asia/Kolkata"
} }}`

Comment: I am using this query on mongoDB booster 
     db.checkins.aggregate({"$match":{"_id":"E08AF4BD-5539-497E-
         B8DA-51AD1A14F7A7"}},{"$project":{"checkinData.time":1, 
        $hour: { date: "$checkinData.time", timezone: "Asia/Kolkata" }
      }}) 
It returns
 "MongoError: Invalid $project :: caused by :: FieldPath field names may not start with '$'."

Comment: You will need mongo 3.6 version for this and you are missing field name. Check my earlier comment.

Comment: I am using 4,2.0 version..

Comment: Done @Veeram. Thanks !